# Add one item in a list, ask if another is required

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I want to ask my user "Do you need to add another company?" and if they answer yes, they will be able to add a company's name, a date they have sent a request and then a date they expect a response.

Something like:

Company 1:      ABC Ltd

Date sent:      13/5/2019

Date expected:  20/5/2019

Add another company? Yes/No

If Yes, add Company 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow on the first list.

Using if condition, if Add another company is equals Yes, create list item in the second list.

If there is any problem, feel free to let us know.